# Consequences of the axioms of connection and order

Tags: geometry

How do I prove that:

Theorem 4. If we have given any finite number of points situated upon a straight
line, we can always arrange them in a sequence A, B, C, D, E,. . ., K so that B shall
lie between A and C, D, E,. . ., K; C between A, B and D, E,. . . , K; D between
A, B, C and E,. . .K, etc. Aside from this order of sequence, there exists but one
other possessing this property namely, the reverse order K,. . . , E, D, C, B, A.

I know it is a generalization of the theorem that states that: Between any two points of a straight line, there always exists an unlimited number of points.

But can I directly say that this last theorem proves it easily or is more complicated?

Comment: Cannot understand the question. Place $A$ anywhere on the line, translate by 1 to get $B$, again to get $C$, and so on? This is not a generalization of the second theorem. Are $A,K$ fixed?

Comment: The theorem you cite is of no use in this case. You need some axiom or theorem stating that given three point exactly one of them is between the other two, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, that was precisely what I wanted to know. And with that theorem or axiom that you mention could the theorem be solved complete?